# iOS: different HUE colors from Photoshop

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, hue, ciimage

I am using the Hue filter to change the hue of an images, Slider minimum: -3.14 Slider maximum: 3.14 I’m getting hue with darker colors, while photoshop has lighter version. Can anyone help me out this?
[image]
[image]

```
func rotateHue(with ciImage: CIImage, rotatedByHue deltaHueRadians: CGFloat, orientation:UIImageOrientation?, screenWidth:CGFloat, screenHeight:CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    // Create a Core Image version of the image.
    let sourceCore = ciImage
    let resultCore = CIFilter(name: "CIHueAdjust", withInputParameters: [kCIInputImageKey: sourceCore, kCIInputAngleKey: deltaHueRadians])?.outputImage? .cropped(to: sourceCore.extent)

    // Convert the filter output back into a UIImage.
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)

    // let resultRef = context.createCGImage((vignette?.outputImage)!, from: (vignette?.outputImage!.extent)!)
    let resultRef = context.createCGImage(resultCore!, from: (resultCore!.extent))
    var result:UIImage? = nil
    if(orientation != nil) {
        result = UIImage(cgImage: resultRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: orientation!)
    } else {
        result = UIImage(cgImage: resultRef!)
    }        
    return result!
}
```

Comment: are you paid by lines, or why do you even put new lines between function parameters?

Comment: Two comments, neither of which really answers your issue. (1) If you already have `ciImage` coming in as a `CIImage`, why are you creating `sourceCore`? You should simply use what is being passed into the function. (2) Be careful about creating `context` inside your function, as this is *very* expensive and if you call this function multiple times you'll see a performance hit. Instead, create one outside of the function and pass it in - or even create a shared one for your entire app.

Comment: Added comments. (1) Depending on your needs, consider *not* converting into a `UIImage` in the function. Let the caller do that. (2) Speaking of that, what are you doing with this UImage? This may be your issue. If you are using a `UIImageView`, maybe consider using an `MTKView instead - this uses the GPU and is faster. Remember, a `CIImage` isn't an actual image, it's only a "recipe" to manipulate/render an image. (3) Finally, consider that Photoshop likely *doesn't* simply use CIHueAdjust but instead created their own.